# rename a part of file name in windows command (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I want to replace some part of a file name of the existing one .
Delimiter here is "_"

> Say file name is : test_two.txt
>
> The part of file name to replace is  test over here :
>
> So new name will be : Pass_two.txt

I have written something below to achieve :

```
for  %%f  in ("C:\Test_bat\rename file part\*.txt")  do ( 
echo "%%~nxf"
SET FNAME="%%~nxf"
)

   for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in (%FNAME%) do (
   echo %%b
   echo %%~xb 
**-- not sure why i am not getting anything in %%b**
 )
```

when executing the above snippet via windows command promt i face the below issue :

> do( was unexpected at this time

==========Update Solution ===

I was missing the quotes foe below for 
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in (**"%FNAME%"**)

Comment: You need a space between the **`do`** and the opening parenthesis **`(`**. Additionally you could do this **`Ren "C:\Test_bat\rename file part\test_*.txt" "pass_*.txt"`**

Comment: @Compo the name i have to fetch from other file name , it is not pre-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving your goal. *(the most common way would be to use a for loop and tokenising using the **`_`** delimiter)*

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("C:\Test_bat\rename file part\*_*.txt") Do (Set "_=%%A"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%A" "part_!_:*_=!"
    EndLocal)
```

Comment: tx for your help finally i got it done what was needed , Thanks for pointing that space thing after do .